# Removing a specific element from an array by name in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, array-splice

I would like to remove a specific element from an array, not by index because the index value of that item is not static.

```
myarray.splice(myclip, 1);
```

When I use this code instead flash removes the first element in the array.
Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice()) ? Both parameters need to be integers, the first one is the **position** of the element you want to delete, and the second one is the amount of elements you want to delete. Try `myarray.splice(myarray.indexOf(myclip),1);` Don't know why it would only remove the first element in your snippet, maybe internally it casts `myclip` to 0? Doesn't matter, use `indexOf`. If that doesn't work, for loop through the array to get the position first.

Comment: works great, add it as an answer so I can select it and mark as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation of splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice())

Both parameters need to be integers, the first one is the position of the element you want to delete, and the second one is the amount of elements you want to delete. Try `myarray.splice(myarray.indexOf(myclip),1);`

Don't know why it would only remove the first element in your snippet, maybe internally it casts `myclip` to 0? Doesn't matter, use `indexOf`. If that doesn't work, for loop through the array to get the position first.

Comment: myarray.indexOf(myclip) allows me to select the element by name and converts it into a number for splice

Comment: You may find for removing a single element that `myarray.removeAt(myarray.indexOf(myclip));` is more concise.